# How to glue several macros together?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three macros written for Excel. They work as if I wanted to - but I don't want to do them separately (they execute them for a few files). Could someone help me glue these macros together to make my work easier?

Below is a code that works the way I want it to. It is broken down into three separate macros.

```vb
Sub ETAP1()
'
' ETAP1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("I12").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
        :="PROGNOZA_05_2019"
End Sub



Sub ETAP2()
'
' ETAP2 Makro
'

'
    Selection.Replace What:="PROGNOZA_05_2019", Replacement:="PROGNOZA_06_2019" _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    'Columns("K:U").Select
    'Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
        :="PROGNOZA_06_2019"


End Sub

Sub ETAP3()
'
' ETAP3 Makro
'

'
    Columns("K:U").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=12
    Range("K:U,AZ:BJ,BL:CA,CC:CO,CQ:DC,DE:DQ,DS:EE").Select
    Range("DS1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T_BGT_104_2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=136, _
        Criteria1:="1,00"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 94
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 80
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Sheets("A_BGT_104-2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I would ask you to help me combine these three macros into one.

Comment: Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final Macro has to start with

```
Sub ETAP1()
```

and end with

```
End Sub
```

Just delete the `Sub ETAP2()`, `Sub ETAP3()` and the `End Sub` in between.

Your final Macro will look like this:

```
Sub ETAP1()
'
' ETAP1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("I12").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
        :="PROGNOZA_05_2019"

    Selection.Replace What:="PROGNOZA_05_2019", Replacement:="PROGNOZA_06_2019" _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    'Columns("K:U").Select
    'Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
        :="PROGNOZA_06_2019"

   Columns("K:U").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=12
    Range("K:U,AZ:BJ,BL:CA,CC:CO,CQ:DC,DE:DQ,DS:EE").Select
    Range("DS1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T_BGT_104_2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=136, _
        Criteria1:="1,00"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 94
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 80
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 63
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Sheets("A_BGT_104-2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows _
        :=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Additionally check the [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1) to make your code cleaner, faster and easier to manage

Answer (score 0):

Add a new sub and then call ETAP1, ETAP2 and ETAP3.

Like the below :

```
Sub ETAP()
    ETAP1
    ETAP2
    ETAP3
End Sub
```

Comment: This would cause a [syntax-error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/syntax-error). [Parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code) are only used when returning something. Also, asking the user to accept your answer in your answer is probably not the best etiquette for this site.

Comment: @RobertTodar, thanks for your input, modified my answer accordingly.